# Need some clarification of DNN Evoq

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm DNN developer but didn't know much more about DNN Evoq. I need to convert my website from Professional Edition to Evoq. Current website has 28 custom modules, 1 skin and 100+ Pages.

**My Questions:**

1. Can I integrate current website modules in Evoq?
2. Can I directly upgrade current website version to Evoq?
3. Can I integrate current website skin in Evoq?
4. Can I install Evoq in my own servers?
5. I already have license of Professional Version, still I need to pay for Evoq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, a module for DNN PE or even DNN Platform, should work unless you use any of the deprecated functionality (might require a recompile)
2. Yes, just as you would do any DNN upgrade, you can upgrade from PE to EVOQ
3. Most likely
4. that's a DNN Corp Licensing question
5. that's a DNN Corp Licensing question

Comment: Yes, they provide an _UPGRADE.zip file like they do with all other releases